# mapping RegEx to additional "instruction" using a dictonary

Tags: python, regex, dictionary

I looked over some old Java code of mine, in which I extracted dates and their formats, from a number of strings. It was a terrible mess of if conditions and regex patterns and matchers.
So I thought about how I would solve this nowadays and in Python. I have a number of regex patterns which map to a date format, from which susequently a time stamp is created. I heard "If there is a switch statement in Java, in Python there should be a dictonary":

```
pattern_dic = {
    "[\\d]{2}:[\\d]{2}, .{3} [\\d]{1,2}, [\\d]{4} \\(UTC\\)": "HH:mm, MMM dd, yyyy (zzz)",
    "[\d]{2}:[\d]{2}, [\d]{1,2} .{3} [\d]{4} \(UTC\)"       : "HH:mm, dd MMM yyyy (zzz)",
    ...
}
```

*I think that I have to change these date patterns because I just copied them from the Java solution.

In another problem in which I had regex / replacement pairs, I found a pretty nice solution using the dictionary like this
(courtesy to some brilliant person on Stack Overflow). This works only if the matching regex is a simple string, so it can looked up in the dictionary (I think).

```
pattern_acc = re.compile(r'\b(' + '|'.join(pattern_dic.keys()) + r')\b')
comment = pattern_acc.sub(lambda x: pattern_dic[x.group()], comment)
```

Here is what I came up with so far. My problem is that I don't know how i can get the matching part of the regex to look up in my dictionary ("matching_date_pattern"):

```
def multi_match(input_string, pattern_dic):
    date_pattern = re.compile(r'\b(' + '|'.join(pattern_dic.keys()) + r')\b')
    matches = date_pattern.findall(input_string)

    date_formats = []
    for match in matches:
        matching_string = match.group()
        date_format = pattern_dic["matching_date_pattern"]
        date_formats.append((matching_string, date_format))
```

**edit:**
I should have stated that I would like to solve this as a preliminary problem. I would like to separate the matching and the searching. While being able to access the matching pattern.
Think for example if the regular expressions consist of many groups and the "instructions" they are matched to become more complex. Imagine for example that you expect a lot of different text objects, like links, markdown elements, and so on. My problem in the moment boils down to knowing which pattern matched, between matching and searching.

Maybe the  question is also how expensive it is to compile patterns, since compiling them separately of course make it easier  to access them.

Comment: It i s easier to just iterate over the patterns and get the required value once a match is found.

Answer (score 0):

This code you snatched from Stack Overflow is good is you want to match **any** of multiple regexps, but doesn't solve your problem of finding **which** of your regexps matched in every particular case. You should rather just iterate over `pattern_dic` and check every key in turn:

```
def multi_match(input_string, pattern_dic):
    for regexp in pattern_dic:
        re.search(regexp, input_string)
        matching_string = match.group()
        date_format = pattern_dic[regexp]
        date_formats.append((matching_string, date_format))
    return date_formats
```

Side remark: `.append` takes one argument, so it is necessary to form a tuple - thus additional pair of parentheses.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I've edited the question and eddited some reasoning why I want to sepperate matching and searching.

Comment: But still you are probably right in a sense that I sould compile the patterns individually.

Comment: If the number of regexps is not very high, you don't really need to compile them explicitly, as Python does that for you and caches the result. If, however, you have lots of them (lots being >512, if I remember correctly), then you'll exceed Python's cache and so compiling them yourself is a good idea.